# Multiple $_GET from a link parameters

Tags: php, parameters, get

I'm sending values to php file using js like that:

```
validation.php?firstName=test?lastName=test?email=test?contactNumber=test?title=test?description=test
```

And in validation.php I've created array with these values like that:

```
$data[0] = $_GET['firstName'];
$data[1] = $_GET['lastName'];
$data[2] = $_GET['email'];
$data[3] = $_GET['contactNumber'];
$data[4] = $_GET['title'];
$data[5] = $_GET['description'];
```

unfortunately php returns me errors, why?

Comment: Which errors? You should add the error messages to your question so it's more clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 12):

`?` indicates the start of a query string but key/value pairs within it are separated with `&` or (less commonly) `;`.

Comment: In context of PHP the `;` is misleading, `?a=b;c=d` results in `$_GET["a"] = "b;c=d"`. See as well http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2

Comment: How odd, I thought PHP had [got that right](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2). Oh well, one more thing to add to my list of reasons I dislike PHP.

Comment: That example I gave was only the default setting, it can be changed [`arg_separator.input = ";&"`](http://php.net/arg_separator.input).

Answer (score 6):

You need to separate them with the ampersand sign:

```
validation.php?firstName=test&lastName=test&email=test&contactNumber=test&title=test&description=test
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the & instead of the ? in the url between variables.

Answer (score 1):

your URL is wrong. Make it like:

```
validation.php?firstName=test&lastName=test&email=test&contactNumber=test&title=test&description=test
```