# PHP Running/GET Statements

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need help with Get Statements and Running on a site on PHP
I have this a my PHP code

[image: PHP CODE]

---

This is how I save it but it only saves username ...

http://example.com/NC0.php?U=namehere

I have tried this below but it doesn't work

http://example.com/NC0.php?U=namehere?P=passhere

How can I make it like........ NC0.php?U=namehere?P=passhere

or something similar thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple $\_GET from a link parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387481/multiple-get-from-a-link-parameters)

Comment: Please paste actual code here and not a picture of it

Comment: You would be better off tagging php but I suspect @Lachie has given the right answer.

Comment: @KGProductions If my answer worked for you please press the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `?` multiple times. It is meant to start the query! To have multiple parameters in the URL you use the `&` symbol to differentiate the parameters.

For example,

http://example.com/NC0.php?U=namehere&P=passhere